# Programmatically formatting HTML in Eclipse workspace

Tags: html, eclipse, format

I like Eclipse's HTML formatter. It is the best formatter I have seen and I want to use it programmatically. Is it possible? And how?

Thank you greg-449, but your advice is too difficult for me.

I have an lxml based XHTML-to-XHTML converter. I am using it mainly from PyDev. Its output is not so much human-readable and that is not what I want.

I know several ways to format XHTML. And I like Eclipse's formatter the best.

Comment: Use it programmatically where? It is probably possible to use it in an Eclipse plug-in on a `SourceViewer` object.

Answer (score 1):

eclipse's html formatter class is org.eclipse.wst.html.core.internal.format.HTMLFormatter

you can get the source code and remove dependencies to other eclipse libraries in the class and use it...

you can find the source from [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/23013693/) (and some other places)